# ExtJS 5 - Chained Store Binding with Form Field Error (MVVM)

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

anyone who tried and succeeded binding form fields with chainedstore in ExtJs 5 with MVVM pattern?
It works well with grid but not for the textfield, radio or checkbox. Struggling for a week but no luck yet.

Here is fiddle,
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7cn

Expecting value but it keeps showing [object Object] no matter what :-(
Also expect the binding when removing the teen record from {everyone} grid.

Best regards,
Chad

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the whole store to form fields and because the store is an object it shows [object Object] as a value of the field. You have to bind a record field to the form field when it shows the actual value in the field and sends the changed value back to the record field.

Thus you need a *selected record* form any of your stores and you need to bind your form fields to the fields of that record.

To see it in action:

- http://extjs.eu/examples/#bind-grid-form
- http://extjs.eu/examples/#complex-data-binding-5

Comment: Thank you Saki. I left same question in your website.:-) Is it possible to make direct binding with viewModel without grid buffer somehow? Maybe using formular?

Comment: Possibly. But binding what to what. There are always two (or more) participants in binding.